# Borel Sets and Borel Functions

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, self-learning, lebesgue-measure

I read the following argument in Billingsley (1995). Consider a function $F(x)$ and define four associated quantities at $x$:

$$
D^F(x) := \limsup_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}; \\
D_F(x) := \liminf_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}; \\
^{F}D(x) := \limsup_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{F(x)-F(x-h)}{h}; \\
_{F}D(x) := \liminf_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{F(x)-F(x-h)}{h}.
$$

It is clear that $F$ has a derivative at $x$ if and only if the above four quantities exist and equal. Now assume that $F$ is measurable and non-decreasing and hence has at most countably many discontinuity points. Let $M$ be a countable and dense set containing all these discontinuity points. Moreover, let $r_n(x)$ be the smallest number of the form $\frac{k}{n}$ exceeding $x$. Then it claims that:

$$
D^F(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{\substack{x<y<r_n(x) \\ y\in M}} \frac{F(y)-F(x)}{y-x}.
$$

Furthermore, it is claimed that the function inside the limit is measurable because the $x$-set where it exceeds $\alpha$ is

$$
\cup_{y\in M} \{x: x<y<r_n(x), F(y)-F(x)>\alpha(y-x)\}. (*)
$$

Therefore, it concludes that $D^F(x)$ is measurable but it may well be infinite. Similarly the other three quantities $D_F(x), ^{F}D(x)$ and $_{F}D(x)$ are measurable, too. Finally, the set where the four quantities have a common finite value is a Borel set.

My questions are as follows:

1. I can see why $(*)$ are true. But it took me a while to figure it out. That is, I cannot think of an intuitive way to explain it and remember it. Does anyone have a clever way to make sense of it, please?
2. I still could not see why $D^F(x)$ is measurable. Could anyone explain it, please?
3. Finally, why is the set where the four quantities have a common finite value is Borel, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Since a limit exists iff $\limsup=\liminf$ and the derivative exists iff left derivative = right derivative. Thus you have $2\times 2=4$ limits.

(2) $D^F(x)=\lim_{n→∞}\sup _{x<t<r_n(x)}\frac{F(t)−F(x)}{t−x} = \lim_{n→∞}\sup_{x<y<r_n(x),y∈M}\frac{F(y)−F(x)}{y−x}.$ The first equality can be considered as definition or an equivalent way of formulating the $\limsup$. The second equality is because $M$ is dense and contains all the discontinuous points and $F$ is continuous a.e. (try to take an sequence $t_m$ approaching $\sup _{x<t<r_n(x)}\frac{F(t)−F(x)}{t−x}$ ($n$ ,$x$ fixed) , and you will  see why the second equality is true.).

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ operation still gives us (Borel)measurable function, we only need to show $\sup_{x<y<r_n(x),y∈M}\frac{F(y)−F(x)}{y−x} $ is measurable, which is the same as showing $\cup_{y\in M}\{x: x<y<r_n(x), F(y)-F(x)>\alpha(y-x)\}$ is measurable. As $\frac{F(y)-F(x)}{y-x}$ is measurable for fixed $y$ and there is countably many $y$, we see $(*)$ is a measurable set and thus $D^F$ is measurable.

(3) The set for  four quantities have a common finite value is Borel since you could write the set as $\{x: D_F(x)=D^F(x)\}\cap \{x: D_F(x)=^FD(x)\}\cap\{x:D_F(x)=_FD(x)\}\cap\{x: D_F(x)<\infty\}\cap\{x: D^F(x)<\infty\}\cap\{x: _FD(x)<\infty\}\cap\{x: ^FD(x)<\infty\}$. Since $D$s are all Borel measurable, the sets are all Borel measurable and so is their intersection.

Are you self-learning measure-theoretic probability ?

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It is not so clear to me what the difference between Borel and measurable here. It seems that it is Borel simply because the function is assumed to be in $\mathbb R$. BTW, yes, I am self-learning some probability for my thesis.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The reason all the $D$ or $F$ are Borel measurable simply because they are map from $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})\mapsto (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ and thus measurable simply means Borel measurable and $D^{-1}(B),B\in \mathcal{B}$ are always Borel. In general, we say $F: (\Omega, \mathcal{A})\mapsto (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ measurable if $F^{-1}(B),\forall B\in \mathcal{B},$ always measurable. In this case $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$, so we end up with Borel measurable function.