# Borel measurability of $\limsup_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ and $\liminf_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ for arbitrary $f$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is any real-valued function. Prove that $\limsup_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ and $\liminf_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ are Borel measurable.

This problem is hard since we have a weak assumption of $f$. I can prove the case when $f$ is measurable, so I'd like to know how to solve with a general case.

When $f$ is measurable, my approach is similar to what is described here:

[Borel Sets and Borel Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162719/borel-sets-and-borel-functions/1162842#1162842)

Comment: How did you solve the case where $f$ is measurable?

Comment: i think $\liminf$ measurable follows from $\limsup$ measurable, so u shud just ask for $\limsup$ measurable. have u done the case when $f= 1_E$, i.e. $f$ is the characteristic function of some set?

Comment: I assume you ask about Borel-measurability of functions $\overline{f}(x)=\limsup_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ and $\underline{f}(x)=\liminf_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$. But it can happen that for some $x$ a value of  $\overline{f}(x)$ or 
$\underline{f}(x)$ is not a real number. Since in order to investigate a measurability of a function we need to be given a family of the measurable subsets of its range, we can assume that for each real $x$, both values $\overline{f}(x)$ and $\underline{f}(x)$ are reals. But then the function $f$ is continuous at $x$ and so measurable.

Comment: @AlexRavsky you can talk about measurable functions with codomain extended reals